# Hovering over keywords causes glowing on certain words in a sentence/paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a sentence/paragraph like "I like to ride my bicycle every day." etc. and above the paragraph there should be categories: "Nouns", "Verbs" etc. When the user hovers over "Nouns", it should cause "bicycle" and "day" to glow and hovering over "Verbs" it should be "like" and "ride". I think maybe this could be done with span tags around the particular words setting the class to either "noun" or "verb" and some kind of CSS and/or JS. Can anyone help?

Just to be clear, this is what I'm talking about.

```
Nouns - Verbs

I like to ride my bicycle every day.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. I hope it helps to get the base idea

```js
function selectWords(name) {
    let words = document.getElementById("words").children;
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].className === name) {
            words[i].classList.add("selected");
        } else {
            words[i].classList.remove("selected");
        }
    }
}

let selects = document.getElementsByClassName("select");

for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    selects[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
        selectWords(this.dataset.words);
    });
    selects[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        selectWords("empty");
    });
}
```

```css
.selected {text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px red}
```

```html
<div id="words"><span>I</span> <span class="verb">like</span> <span class="verb">to ride</span> <span>my</span> <span class="noun">bicycle</span> <span>every</span> <span class="noun">day</span></div> 
<div class="select" data-words="noun">Nouns</div>
<div class="select" data-words="verb">Verbs</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. You're right, this solution is actually more flexible as it gives me the option to add more categories.

Comment: @Rob Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confused why everyone else was making this so hard. It makes me wonder if I've misunderstood you as well, but I'm pretty sure I haven't.

I used mouseenter and mouseleave, with a system of ids and divs to accomplish what you're looking for.

I used jQuery to accomplish this, so make sure you include the jQuery library.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
/* Beginning of Verbs */
    $("#verb").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".verb").css("text-shadow", "1px 1px 1px blue");
    });
    $("#verb").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".verb").css("text-shadow", "");
    });
  /* Ending of Verbs */
  
  /* Beginning of Nouns */
    $("#noun").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".noun").css("text-shadow", "1px 1px 1px red");
    });
    $("#noun").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".noun").css("text-shadow", "");
    });
    /* Ending of Nouns */
});
```

```css
#verb {

}

.verb {
text-shadow: none;
display: inline;
}
#noun {
  
}

.noun {
text-shadow: none;
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span id ="noun">Nouns</span> - <span id="verb">Verbs</span></p>

<div class="noun">I</div> like to <div class="verb">ride</div> <div class="noun">my</div> bicycle every day.
```

Comment: That's perfect, that's what I was looking for, a glowing effect around the edge of the text. You understood the question exactly.

Comment: Nothing personal but I'm curious why this answer is accepted: mine does exactly the same, but it was written 5 hours earlier. Moreover, it uses no external libraries, just plain javascript. And it reuses the code, so if you have 8 parts of speech (like in English), you don't have to write the same code 8 times. @RobKwasowski

Comment: @KirillSimonov I'm not sure what his answer would be, but in my personal opinion, your code wasn't exactly asker friendly and easy enough for him to go back and change. You're right, your answer was more advanced and correct, however, I can see that he's just looking for a simple code that he himself can understand and edit in the future.

Comment: I agree, jQuery is easier to use and read, but I don't see anything unfriendly in plain js

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each word in a tag, for example, `<span>` and use CSS `:before` or `:after` pseudo element to render the generated content.

```js
onload = function () {

  var confirmation = document.querySelector(".confirm_selection");

  var grammar = {
    "I": "noun",
    "like": "adverb",
    "to": "preposition",
    "ride": "verb",
    "my": "noun",
    "bicycle": "noun",
    "every": "adjective",
    "day": "noun"
  };
  
  Object.entries(grammar).forEach(function([word, key]) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = word;
    span.className = key;
    confirmation.appendChild(span);
  })

}
```

```css
.confirm_selection {
  -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
  transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
  top: 50px;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.confirm_selection:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}

.confirm_selection [class]:hover:before {
  content: attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -24px;
  background: #000;
  color: gold;
  z-Index: 2;
  max-width: 78px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.confirm_selection span {
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!-- overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; -->
<div class="confirm_selection" style="opacity: 1; ">[ Confirm Selection ]</div>
```

Comment: That's not quite what I was hoping for. I've edited my question now and at the bottom it should be clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean only "noun" or "verb" should be highlighted when the word is hovered?

Comment: The idea is not to hover over the actual words in the sentence, but the categories above. Hovering over one of the categories should highlight all instances of that category.

Comment: You can use the same pattern at Answer in reverse

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="context"
  <span class="verb">verb</span> not a verb
  <span class="verb">another verb</span>
</div>

var verbs = document.querySelectorAll('.verb');
var bindEvent = function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < verbs.length; i++) {
      verbs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';    
    }
  })
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < verbs.length; i++) {
      verbs[i].style.backgroundColor = '';    
    }
  })
}
for (var i = 0; i < verbs.length; i++) {
  bindEvent(verbs[i]);
}
```

i think this codes may help you?

Comment: I've tried to explain a bit better now. I want it like this:

Nouns - Verbs
I like to ride my bicycle every day.

When you hover over "Nouns" all the nouns in the sentence glow.

Comment: The idea is not to hover over the actual words in the sentence, but the categories above. Hovering over one of the categories should highlight all instances of that category.

Comment: I think my plan can solve your problem? Hovering over one of the categories[class="verb"] should highlight all instances of that category[all class="verb"]